# Material change in animation - Need help

Tags: materials

I need one help..I am trying to change the material of the mesh through key frame say frame 1 is white and frame 5 is blue i tried doing this through hovering in color pane insert key frame but the problem i am facing is when i change color in key frame 5 to blue all previous frames are becoming blue...could you please help me what am i missing here...i am trying this in cycle render version 2.79.

Comment: That would normally indicate you have not insert a keyframe on frame 1. You the Dope sheet to see exactly where keyframes are and the Graph editor to check the details.